# How can I use nested for/each loops to create objects with different features?

Tags: java, arrays, string, object

I'm trying to create a deck of cards (based on the SET game) that has 81 unique cards. I'm trying to accomplish this by using three generalized for loops. Now, I have three arrays of Strings with the features (shapes, colors, patterns). However, upon adding `println` statements into the loops, I found out that only red cards are created with only one type of pattern.

```
ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

static public Deck create() {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    String[] shapes = new String[] { "diamond", "squiggly", "oval",
            "double diamond", "double squiggly", "double oval",
            "triple diamond", "triple squiggly", "triple oval" };
    String[] colors = new String[] { "red", "green", "purple" };
    String[] patterns = new String[] { "stripes", "filled in", "outlined" };
    // Shapes
    for (String shape : shapes) {
        System.out.println(shape);
        // Colors
        for (String color : colors) {
            System.out.println(color);

            // Patterns
            for (String pattern : patterns) {
                System.out.println(pattern + "\n");
                Card card = new Card(shape, color, pattern);
                deck.deck.add(card);


                break;
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    return null;

}
```

This is the output:

```
diamond
red
stripes

squiggly
red
stripes

oval
red
stripes

double diamond
red
stripes

double squiggly
red
stripes

double oval
red
stripes

triple diamond
red
stripes

triple squiggly
red
stripes

triple oval
red
stripes
```

Now, it's supposed to create all the shapes with each individual pattern and shape. I'm totally lost with this, and I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `break` statements in your code. The break statements causes the inner loops to terminate prematurely.

I've tested your code and it generates 81 cards without the break statements. See this example:

http://ideone.com/SVsXPi

Comment: What's causing the confusion here is probably that you're only printing the `shape` *once* per shape iteration. If you move the `System.out.println` statements into the inner most loop (as I've done in the ideone-example) it will make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Remove your `break;` sections. You're ending your internal for-loops after the first execution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `break` statements since they terminate your loops before you manage to iterate over the data.